# Collapse Wrapper div to inline-block children

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table from divs set to "display:inline-block;".  Wanting to achieve 1px borders throughout the table, I thought it would be efficient to add a RIGHT & BOTTOM border to each child div (each table cell) and then add a wrapper with a TOP & LEFT border to complete the table.  It seems to work well, with one exception:  the width of the #table_wrapper div will not collapse to the combined width of its children.  Any Explanations?  I appreciate explanations of WHY THIS? and WHY NOT THAT? in addition to examples of code.

```
    #splash
    {
    width:700px; 
    height:150px; 
    background-color:#8DEE8C;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #table_wrapper
    {
    border-width:1px; 
    border-right:0; 
    border-bottom:0; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#000000;
    font-size:0; /* to collapse white space (from hitting return in editor) b/w inline-block children */
    }

    #table_wrapper div
    {
    width:119px; 
    height:20px;
    background-color:#F5F5DB;
    border-top:0; 
    border-left:0; 
    border-right:1px; 
    border-bottom:1px; 
    border-style:solid; 
    border-color:#000000;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
    }

    <div id="splash">
        <div id="table_wrapper">
            <div>column 1</div>
            <div>column 2</div>
            <div>column 3</div>
            <div>column 4</div>
            <div>column 5</div>
            <div>column 1</div>
            <div>column 2</div>
            <div>column 3</div>
            <div>column 4</div>
            <div>column 5</div>
            <div>column 1</div>
            <div>column 2</div>
            <div>column 3</div>
            <div>column 4</div>
            <div>column 5</div>
            <div>column 1</div>
            <div>column 2</div>
            <div>column 3</div>
            <div>column 4</div>
            <div>column 5</div>
            <div>column 1</div>
            <div>column 2</div>
            <div>column 3</div>
            <div>column 4</div>
            <div>column 5</div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Simply because the wrapper does not cover the left border which was given as 0px. here's a working fiddle.  It will help you to understand why.
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/4GHUS/

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Can you repost the jsfiddle link?  It took me to a blank jsfiddle page.